# Area 30cms under a sin curve

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

the question I'm trying to solve is calculating the area $30$ units under a sin curve. I am aware I can translate the curve down 30 units and calculate the bounded area, but I need $30$ centimeters of thickness at every point of the curve perpendicular to the curve, [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMm9a.png).
I have tried solving using trig, but am unable to find a function exactly $30$ units away, while being perpendicular at each point.
Any help would be appreciated.
$f(x)=25\space \sin(40^{-1}\times x) + 50$

Comment: Your new curve is a so-called "offset curve" or ["parallel curve"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677497/parallel-curve-to-a-sine-wave). Generaly speaking, equations of such curves are awfully complicated. Consider finding a numerical solution, i.e., an approximation of the result.

Comment: You could modify the units on the two axes: $y=25\space \sin(40^{-1}\times x) + 50$ with $x=10X$ and $y=10Y$ to get the simpler expression $Y=2.5 \ \sin(X/4) + 5$

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate @Jean Marie's comment, using the parametrization given in the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677497/parallel-curve-to-a-sine-wave) he provided ,$$x = t + \frac{d\,\cos (t)}{\sqrt{1 + \cos^2 (t)}}\qquad \qquad y=\sin(t)-\frac{d}{\sqrt{1 + \cos^2 (t)}}$$after some simplifications, we face the problem of computing
$$I=\int \sqrt{\frac{\left((\cos (2 t)+3)^{3/2}-2 \sqrt{2} d \sin (t)\right)^2}{2 (\cos (2 t)+3)^2} }\,dt$$ which is doable (a CAS knows !)

For more clarity, writing the result as
$$I=\frac{\text{numerator}}{\text{denominator}}$$ we have
$$\text{numerator}=(\cos (2 t)+3) \sqrt{\frac{\left((\cos (2 t)+3)^{3/2}-2 \sqrt{2} d \sin (t)\right)^2}{(\cos (2 t)+3)^2}} \times $$ $$
   \left(\sqrt{2} d \tan ^{-1}(\cos (t))+2 E\left(t\left|\frac{1}{2}\right.\right)\right)$$ and
$$\text{denominator}=\sqrt{2} (\cos (2 t)+3)^{3/2}-4 d \sin (t)$$