# Sine wave with thickness

Tags: trigonometry

I've been trying to understand the math behind the offset of a sine wave necessary to represent a sine wave with even thickness.

The naive (and wrong) approach would be to just offset the height of the sine wave in order to generate the offset. The problem with this is that the thickness of the resulting geometry would be thinnest at the point where the sine wave transitions the $x$ axis ($45$ degrees, $\pi/2$ radians).

In order to solve it, I used parametric equations that look at the slope of the sine wave and calculate a new $x_0 = x+\Delta x, y_0 = y+\Delta y$ that represent a new point, and I believe I have the math correct:

$$\begin{split}
x      &= t\\
\Delta x &= \frac{T\sin(t)}{\sqrt2}\\
y      &= H\cos(t)\\
\Delta y &= T\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2} + \frac12\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)(\cos(2t)+1)\right)
\end{split}$$

where $T$ is thickness and $H$ is height.

I believe this is correct, and seems to graph correctly, but now I'm trying to find the non-parametric version of this equation.  I'd like to find a function of $x$ that returns the height of that new curve.

Comment: I have edited your question so the math has MathJax (LaTeX) formatting. Please do check it over to make sure things are correct. I was not entirely sure whether the "delta" in "delta x" was supposed to be a $\delta$ or a $\Delta$, so I took a reasonable guess.

Comment: Incidentally, the term of art here is ["parallel curve"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve). See also the question ["Parallel curve to a sine wave"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1677497/409).

Comment: Other synonym : "offset curves" of a given curve.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I had the math incorrect, but as Blue pointed out, the term of art is "parallel curve", and is it turns out, what I'm looking for is impossible.  There is no $f(x)$ form for the parallel curve.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this *comment*; do not use answer fields to comment.

Comment: I would say there is an $f(x)$ for this particular parallel curve, but not a closed-form expression for it according to the usual ideas of closed-form expressions. The way to compute $f(x)$ given $x$ is via successive approximations using the parametric form. I suppose that particular point of view is useless to you, however.